# Get first word from strange string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this string like that: `var name = "\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\tName\n\t\t\n\n\t\t(send picture)\n\t\n"`
I'd like to get first word (in this example --> Name).

I've tried regex expression, but I couldn't write proper one.
My try:

```
`first_name = name.match(/^([\w\-]+)/)`
```

Comment: Try this `first_name = name.match(/([\w]+)/)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `\w+` to match a *alphanumeric characters with underscore*

```js
var name = "\n\n\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\tName\n\t\t\n\n\t\t(send picture)\n\t\n";
var matches = name.match(/\w+/g);
if (matches) {
  console.log("First word - ", matches[0]);
}
```

**Demo**

Comment: @Xatenev I tested before posting here.